# Issue with Booth multiplier

Tags: verilog

I coded a 4 bit booth multiplier in Verilog. It is working fine for

```
Multiplicand          Multiplier
+ 0 to 7        0 to +7 &  -1 to -7
```

But it does not work for

```
multiplicand         Multiplier
-8                 +1 to +7 & -1 to -8
```

Even I'm not getting answer through the algorithm by hand 
example            -8 X 1

```
                 A            Q           Q_0    Control Bits         Cnt 
               0000         0001          0    10  >> Subtraction     4
               1000
               -----
               1000
      ASR      1100         0000          1    01  >> ADD             3
               1000
               -----
               0100
      ASR      0010         0000          0    00   >> ASR            2

      ASR      0001         0000          0    00   >> ASR            1

      ASR      0000         1000          0    00   >> ASR            0

           PRODUCT = 0000 1000 = +8    NOT -8
```

Is it true, that Booth has a limitation that it can multiply only in the range of
           0 to ((2**N) -1) &&  (-1 to -(2**N)-1))

Like in this example

```
       + range  >>  0 to  7  Multiplied by (0 to 7) || ( -1 to -7)
                   -1 to -7  Multiplied by (0 to 7) || ( -1 to -7)
```

and not by -8?

Answer (score 1):

-8 cannot be represented in 4 bits 2's complement.

Follopwing is 9 bit example in which -8 is written in 2's complement (anyways 5bits are enough for -8 )
8   =>    000001000
~8  =>    111110111
                 +1
          ----------
          111111000